# Temporal Tables - "Parameterise" extended SYSTEM_TIME syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Spine    S
    CROSS
    APPLY
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM PersonTemporalTable
        FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF S.DateTimeValueOfInterest
    )            CA
```

It would be much simpler if I left out the "why" of it and stuck to the "what" and "how".
I need to be be able to query a Temporal table for record state at specific points in time - were the syntax above legal, it would do precisely what I am after.
In this case, the table Spine contains a list of DATETIME values of interest.

Is this simply a matter of not using the correct syntax or is it a limitation?
Besides going with dynamic SQL, do you guys have any other suggestions I could try?

Thanks in advance!

---

This is what I landed up doing, based on suggestions by @SQLZim

```
SELECT *
FROM Spine      SP
JOIN PetTemporal    FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL PT  ON  SP.SpineDT >= PT.ValidFrom AND SP.SpineDT < PT.ValidTo
JOIN PersonTemporal FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL PS  ON  SP.SpineDT >= PS.ValidFrom AND SP.SpineDT < PS.ValidTo
                                            AND PS.PersonID = PT.PersonID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return `Spine` rows even if there is no corresponding row in `PersonTemporalTable`, switch to `outer apply()`.

If `PersonTemporalTable` contains an effective date range:

```
select *
from Spine S
  cross apply (
    select ptt.*
    from PersonTemporalTable
    where ptt.FromDateTime <= S.DateTimeValueOfInterest
      and ptt.ThruDateTime >= S.DateTimeValueOfInterest
  ) CA
```

If `PersonTemporalTable` contains a single effective date:

```
select *
from Spine S
  cross apply (
    select top 1 ptt.*
    from PersonTemporalTable ptt
    where ptt.EffectiveDate <= S.DateTimeValueOfInterest
  order by ptt.EffectiveDate desc
  ) CA
```

---

If this is supposed to return rows where the two tables share a corresponding key, e.g. `PersonId`, then include that in the `where` of the `cross apply()`, e.g.:

```
select *
from Spine S
  cross apply (
    select top 1 ptt.*
    from PersonTemporalTable ptt
    where ptt.EffectiveDate <= S.DateTimeValueOfInterest
      and ptt.PersonId = S.PersonId
  order by ptt.EffectiveDate desc
  ) CA
```

---

Another option that takes advantage of the extended `system_time as of` syntax: you could create an inline table-valued function to use with `cross apply()` like so:

```
create function dbo.PersonTemporalTable_AsOf (@fromdate datetime2(7)) returns table as return (
select *
  from PersonTemporalTable
  for system_time as of @fromdate
)
go
select *
from spine s
  cross apply dbo.PersonTemporalTable_AsOf(s.DateTimeValueOfInterest) ca
```

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f1ee20893fe987e71cbd0cb12d09fccb

Comment: You're right; the WHERE clause can solve this. Will mark your answer as correct if no one manages to suggest a method that actually uses the extended temporal syntax :)

Comment: @MarkD I added another option that uses the syntax you specified.

Comment: Nice idea - unfortunately it will mean that I'll need a function per table or a function that takes the table as an argument.
Thank you very much for your help :)